# Question about \begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}

Tags: tables, spacing

This is my first time asking a question on here, so please forgive me if I'm not explaining everything properly. To describe me as a beginner is a massive understatement. But here it goes.

I'm working on my CV, and I keep running into the same problem. The first two lines keep sticking together, and I can't separate them. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{array, xcolor}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.08\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]

\begin{document}

\section*{Publications}

\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}

2021&``Blah blah blah blah.'' \textit{Journal of blah blah blah}. Vol. 1, No. 1, pp. 1-23.\\[5pt]
\vspace{5mm}

2020&``Blah blah blah blah.'' \textit{Journal of blah blah blah}. Vol. 1, No. 1, pp. 1-23.\\[5pt]
\vspace{5mm}

2019&``Blah blah blah blah.'' \textit{Journal of blah blah blah}. Vol. 1, No. 1, pp. 1-23.\\[5pt]
\vspace{5mm}

2018&``Blah blah blah blah.'' \textit{Journal of blah blah blah}. Vol. 1, No. 1, pp. 1-23.\\[5pt]
\vspace{5mm}

2015&``Blah blah blah blah.'' \textit{Journal of blah blah blah}. Vol. 1, No. 1, pp. 1-23.\\[5pt]
\vspace{5mm}

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Apologies again, but I don't know how to use this website, so I don't know how to typeset in the comment to show you what it looks like, but basically there is two problems:

(1) The first two lines (the one that starts with "2021" and the one that starts with "2020" have no spacing between them, and I want them to have spacing. I tried all sorts of things (e.g., \vspace{5mm}) and it doesn't help.

(2) The years that appear on the left-hand side are not aligned with the information on the right-hand side.

Any help would be greatly appreciated it! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative with `tabularray`.
You can set any `rowsep` you like:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\section*{Publications}
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={Q[t,r,wd={0.08\textwidth}]|X},
    vline{2} ={.5pt,lightgray},
    rowsep=5mm,
    row{1}={abovesep=2pt},
    row{Z}={belowsep=2pt},
    }
2021&``Blah blah blah blah.'' \textit{Journal of blah blah blah}. Vol. 1, No. 1, pp. 1-23.\\
2020&``Blah blah blah blah.'' \textit{Journal of blah blah blah}. Vol. 1, No. 1, pp. 1-23.\\
2019&``Blah blah blah blah.'' \textit{Journal of blah blah blah}. Vol. 1, No. 1, pp. 1-23.\\
2018&``Blah blah blah blah.'' \textit{Journal of blah blah blah}. Vol. 1, No. 1, pp. 1-23.\\
2015&``Blah blah blah blah.'' \textit{Journal of blah blah blah}. Vol. 1, No. 1, pp. 1-23.\\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `\vspace` inside a `tabular`.

If you want to increase the vertical space between rows, change the `5pt` length with something else.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{array, xcolor}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.08\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]

\begin{document}

\section*{Publications}

\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}

2021&``Blah blah blah blah.'' \textit{Journal of blah blah blah}. Vol. 1, No. 1, pp. 1-23.\\[5pt]

2020&``Blah blah blah blah.'' \textit{Journal of blah blah blah}. Vol. 1, No. 1, pp. 1-23.\\[5pt]

2019&``Blah blah blah blah.'' \textit{Journal of blah blah blah}. Vol. 1, No. 1, pp. 1-23.\\[5pt]

2018&``Blah blah blah blah.'' \textit{Journal of blah blah blah}. Vol. 1, No. 1, pp. 1-23.\\[5pt]

2015&``Blah blah blah blah.'' \textit{Journal of blah blah blah}. Vol. 1, No. 1, pp. 1-23.

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\\[12pt]` instead of `\\[5pt]` you'd get

[image]

Comment: thank you for that very helpful answer. One more thing: I want spacing between each line. That's why I was using the "\vspace{5mm}." I don't want them to be single-spaced. What's the fix for that?

Comment: @Itsme Isn’t the second example more spaced?